# IE - <a> tag not rendering properly, works in chrome, firefox etc

Tags: css, internet-explorer, stylesheet

I have an issue with the rendering of a  tag on my page in IE. The problem lies in the following; the  tag, in IE does not fill the  tag. The picture is the link but in IE the text takes precedence and overrides the image to make the text a link. Chrome and FireFox have no issues and render fine. My question is:

**How can I make the image the link in IE and get it to work like it does in Chrome and FireFox?**

The following images showcase my problem:
The problem in IE:

[image]

How it should render as per Chrome and FireFox:
[image]

The code for the section is as follows:

```
h1#site-name, div#site-name /* The name of the website */
{
margin: 0;
font-size: 2em;
line-height: 1.3em;
height: 115px;
background: url('/sites/default/files/images/ipark2-theme-assets/iPark_title.jpg') no-repeat top right;
margin-left: 212px;
color: transparent;

}

  #site-name a:link,
  #site-name a:visited
  {
   color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  font-size:1em;
  }
```

EDIT: addition of html markup:

```
 <div id="logo-title">

 <div id="logo"><a href="/" title="Home" rel="home"><img src="/sites/all/themes/zen/ipark2/logo.png" alt="Home" id="logo-image" /></a></div>

 <div id="site-name"><strong>
 <a href="/" title="Home" rel="home">Teaching and Learning Innovation Park</a>
 </strong></div>

 </div> <!-- /#logo-title -->


 </div></div> <!-- /#header-inner, /#header -->
```

Comment: where is your html markup?

Comment: addition of HTML markup @chrisvillanueva

Comment: It looks like you're using an ID twice in your CSS (on the H1 and the div)? Also, why aren't you using classes either, you've chosen to give everything an ID. Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: well, with all that, you can make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) !

Comment: jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vyfr2/

Comment: What DOCTYPE do you use?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Answer (score 0):

You're applying an ID to two elements (your H1 and your div), make use of classes as at the moment you're just slapping an ID on everything.

I'm not sure if that will solve your issue, but it won't hurt and I know older versions of IE are more strict about recognizing an ID if it's not unique. Since you're targeting your anchor tag through that ID, it just makes me question if it isn't the issue.